# How to change the number of decimals for labels using the package metaviz?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the package "metaviz" to display the results of a several different studies. More specifically, I am using the viz_forest function to create a forest plot and I would like the estimates to be shown with CIs to the right of the plot. However, it is automatically rounding to the second decimal place and I would like it to round to the third decimal place.

```
viz_forest(x = dfamce_ordered[1:20, c("amce", "std")],
           study_labels = dfamce_ordered[1:20, c("country")],
           summary_label = "Summary Effect", 
           xlab = "AMCE", 
           annotate_CI = TRUE)
```

##### Data:

```
dfamce_ordered <- structure(list(amce = c(0.102243018346973, 0.0682493096502726, 
0.0669067622543539, 0.0599407268674782, 0.0504396688405717, 0.0484962116195263, 
0.0457041669923713, 0.0430856080509793, 0.0414650636376924, 0.0388962366915576, 
0.0313556995623549, 0.0308907944434052, 0.027261193097714, 0.0270736858953663, 
0.0185393787585495, 0.013927001415788, 0.00989105057091642, 0.00558431178605058, 
-0.00328687062104834, -0.0378235020967646), std = c(0.0121135533945813, 
0.0126226498023255, 0.0124988950034267, 0.0121412322564469, 0.0112794869488059, 
0.0119370400101144, 0.0125916409337608, 0.0116812636593066, 0.0116262083546671, 
0.0119836659476091, 0.0124695971997358, 0.01251991561798, 0.0114894773255983, 
0.012538903134963, 0.0131449572085337, 0.0134171003637553, 0.0144683803996521, 
0.0128400262884722, 0.0119044068536946, 0.0123140943445314), 
    country = c("Brazil", "Spain", "Mexico", "Denmark", "Argentina", 
    "Japan", "Turkey", "Germany", "Romania", "Hungary", "USA", 
    "Kenya", "South Africa", "India", "Nigeria", "Lithuania", 
    "Ukraine", "Morocco", "Malaysia", "Indonesia")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an option within the `metaviz::viz_forest` to change the precision. It is actually hard-coded to round them to 2 decimals; see the snippet below taken from the [source code](https://github.com/Mkossmeier/metaviz/blob/e1686fceb30294503479748edffb288b88153671/R/viz_forest.R#L645):

```
      lb <- format(round(lb, 2), nsmall = 2)
      ub <- format(round(ub, 2), nsmall = 2)
      x_hat <- format(round(x_hat, 2), nsmall = 2)

      CI <- paste(x_hat, " [", lb, ", ", ub, "]", sep = "")
```

You could make a similar plot with `ggplot2` and add your desired labels, but that involves more effort than just calling `viz_forest`. You could also alter the source code and rebuild the package. Bottom line, there isn't a straightforward way to change the precision for those labels.